# I'm wanting to replace some parts

Tags: derailleur

I did some work for my neighbor and he gave me some cash plus a road bike. I've used it for about 3 years but I was wondering if I could upgrade it a little. The chain slips off some times and it's got lever shifters. I don't know anything about road bikes so I was wondering how upgrading the front and rear derailleur works. I found original parts but they are 300$ plus. I just want reliable and affordable. Also the wanting to upgrade the crank and other little parts. All I know is it's an Italvega Nuovo possibly 63.

[image]

Comment: Can you add a picture of the whole bike from the drive (chain) side?

Comment: If by "63" 1963 is meant - that derailleur was made between 1971 and 1974 https://bikeretrogrouch.blogspot.com/2017/01/weird-and-wild-campagnolo-gran-turismo.html

Comment: If you like to ride something new, clean the old bike and sell it. What you may get for a decent Italian bike with Campagnolo components plus the money you'd spend upgrading will get you a nice entry level bike.

Answer (score 6):

I want to tell you you have a classic old bike with original components and you should preserve it that way, but I'll provide some guidance.

Be aware there may be many things that need fixing in order to make the bike truly usable. If you just want a bike that works better for everyday riding an option is to sell the Italvega and buy a used modern bike.

If you want to get the drivetrain working better, you may not actually need to replace the derailleurs or crank. A new chain and freewheel may be enough. You likely have an Italian standard thread size on the hub which is a little different from the modern standard thread size, but according to [this page](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/freewheels.html) a modern freewheel will actually fit.

Replacing the brake and shifter cables and their housings will also make a big difference.

If you need to replace the derailleur the easiest thing to do is get a low-end Shimano Tourney level derailleur that will work just fine with the analog shift levers.

Replacing the crank is a slightly trickier proposition as you very likely have an Italian threaded bottom bracket, which is different from the modern standard. However, I believe Italian threaded square taper axle bottom brackets are available which would allow you to fit an inexpensive new crank.

I'd also want to check out the wheel bearings, head (steering) bearings, and service and regrease them. You may also find that you crank just needs a bearing service if the rings are not too worn.

Answer (score 2):

Often bikes are ridden very little and nothing is worn out. Over time the lubrication and plastic or rubber parts have oxidized. They just need cleaning, lubrication and adjustment - and possibly new tires and brake pads due to extreme age. A little light cleaning and inspection will tell you if parts look worn.

The key issue reported concerning reliability is the chain slipping off. This might be corrected with something as simple as derailleur adjustment or straightening.

Here is a good [Bicycle Stack Exchange answer on adjusting derailleurs](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/55485/gear-problems-on-my-bike/55488#55488).

To add to Argenti's answer, you have a vintage bike. You have choices to make.
Here are a few possibilities:

- Restore it to original and keep it. This would involve cleaning, adjusting and as few parts replacements as possible.
- Modernize it and spend money on new parts (sometimes this is a "slippery slope". As you fix one thing it leads to fixing other things and costs begin to mount)
- Sell it and use the money toward a new bike (don't ask us about value - we don't know)

At the end of the day it's all about what kind of riding you want to do. Are you going to start riding every day to work? once a week or month?
If this bike matches the kind of riding you want to do and you like working on bikes restoration is probably a good answer.
If you are looking for something more comfortable and/or modern selling it might be a good answer.